# Remove array item from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an array i stored(parsed it as json) in localstorage. 
I got it back into an object, removed some items from it and i need to update the key with the new values in the local storage.

```
var counter = [0,1,2];
var count = counter[0];
var questions = localStorage.getItem('questions');///questions had been stored in local storage with another function
console.log(questions);
questions = $.parseJSON(questions);

if (questions != 0){
    $('.question').html(questions[count]['question']);
    var options = (questions[count]['options']);
    options.forEach(function (item) {
        $('.options').html(item);
    });
    var index = counter.indexOf(1);
    questions = questions.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(questions);
    localStorage.removeItem('questions);
    counter = counter.splice(index, 0);
```

Now, when i remove the question key from the local storage, the whole question array is deleted, however, i only need to delete the particular question array that was passed.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of deleting the key, just set it again with the new questions array:

```
questions.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('questions', JSON.stringify(questions));
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `removeItem()` that as the name says removes the whole item from `localStorage`. Just do another `setItem()` to overwrite the old data.

Also you do:

```
questions = questions.splice(index, 1);
```

That is going to remove element(s) from the array and return them. `questions` will then be the removed element(s) and not your modified array. By your question you just want the modified array. So just do the `splice()` without the assignment

So your end code would be:

```
questions.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('questions',JSON.stringify(questions));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared this for you, you can use it as very simple.,

Live example and demo: [LocalStorage Arrays: Add, Remove, Update and Beyond...](https://codepen.io/AmonGames/pen/bGrZzzw)

```
localStorage.setItem('questions', JSON.stringify(questions));
```

Comment: Well, the mentioned example is not a simple way to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just reuse the localStorage you have before. It will automatically update the previous one stored. Use this immediately after the delete method.

```
localStorage.setItem('questions', JSON.stringify(questions));
```