# How to remove an array element from local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of contacts in local storrage, and I need to remove, for example, the first element. How better to do? Is this expression correct?

```
          localStorage.removeItem("allContacts"[0]);
```

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` contains *string* values. If you `stringify`ed an array and put it into `localStorage`, then you'll need to `parse` the array, delete the element you want, and then set the `localStorage` property again:

```
const allContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.allContacts);
allContacts.shift();
localStorage.allContacts = JSON.stringify(allContacts);
```