# How can I add a button onto my list elements that deletes the respective element for a CRUD app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a CRUD app that I'm writing for tracking events, and I want to add a delete button to each list element after it's been added using my add function. I'm using JQuery, vanilla JS, and html. 
I've only been able to iterate through each item and have a button added to each item when a new item is added to the list or when the doc is refreshed, and it ends up deleting each element because of this.

Here is the function to add an item that I need to attach a delete button to using

```
// Add an item to the list
  $("#add-text-btn").on("click", function(){

    // Store values from input boxes
    let inputKey = $("#user-input-title").val();
    let inputValue = $("#user-input-body").val();

    if ($("#user-input-title").val() === "") {
      alert("Task needs a name.")
    } else {
      // Clear values from input boxes
      $("#user-input-title").val("");
      $("#user-input-body").val("");

      // Add new property to local storage from input boxes
      window.localStorage.setItem(inputKey, inputValue);

      // Add inputKey and inputValue to the #display container
      let itemHtml = '<li class="display-item" style="display: none;" data-storage-key="'+inputKey+'"> ' + inputKey + ' on ' + '<span class="description">' + window.localStorage.getItem(inputKey) + '</span></li>';
      $(itemHtml).appendTo("#display").show('slow');
    }
    // addCloseButton();
  });
```

Here's the HTML it links to

```
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1 id="header">Upcoming Events</h1>

  <section id="input">

    <input type="text" id="user-input-title" placeholder="Enter event name:">

    <textarea id="user-input-body" placeholder="Enter event date:"></textarea>

    <textarea  id="user-input-location" placeholder="Enter event location:"></textarea>

    <textarea  id="user-input-time" placeholder="Enter event time:"></textarea>

  </section>

  <section id="buttons">

   <button class="button" id="add-text-btn">Add an event</button>

   <button class="button" id="del-text-btn">Remove event</button>

   <button class="button" id="show-hidden">show hidden</button>

   <button class="button" id="clear-all-btn">Clear events</button>

  </section>

  <span><ul><div id="display"></div></ul></span>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by simply adding on a button to the `<li>` element you are creating. Then with some css you can add a margin onto the button to style it to your desire.

It would end up looking like below in the DOM once it is created.

```
<li id="1">Event Name<button>X</button></li>
```

I then added an onclick function that will then delete the whole `<li>` element based on id. There is probably a better way to do this but that should put you on the right track.

```js
// Add an item to the list

let index = 0;

$("#add-text-btn").on("click", function() {
  index++;
  // Store values from input boxes
  let inputKey = $("#user-input-title").val();
  let inputValue = $("#user-input-body").val();

  if ($("#user-input-title").val() === "") {
    alert("Task needs a name.")
  } else {
    // Clear values from input boxes
    $("#user-input-title").val("");
    $("#user-input-body").val("");

    // Add new property to local storage from input boxes
    // window.localStorage.setItem(inputKey, inputValue);

    // Add inputKey and inputValue to the #display container
    let itemHtml = '<li id="' + index + '" class="display-item" style="display: none;" data-storage-key="' + inputKey + '"> ' + inputKey + ' on ' + '<span class="description">' + index + '</span><button id="btn' + index + '" class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEvent(' + index + ');">X</button></li>';
    $(itemHtml).appendTo("#display").show('slow');
  }
});

function deleteEvent(id) {
  $("#" + id).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="header">Upcoming Events</h1>

  <section id="input">

    <input type="text" id="user-input-title" placeholder="Enter event name:">

    <textarea id="user-input-body" placeholder="Enter event date:"></textarea>

    <textarea id="user-input-location" placeholder="Enter event location:"></textarea>

    <textarea id="user-input-time" placeholder="Enter event time:"></textarea>

  </section>

  <section id="buttons">

    <button class="button" id="add-text-btn">Add an event</button>

    <button class="button" id="del-text-btn">Remove event</button>

    <button class="button" id="show-hidden">show hidden</button>

    <button class="button" id="clear-all-btn">Clear events</button>

  </section>

  <span><ul><div id="display"></div></ul></span>

</body>
```

Comment: Well it also needs to remove the key value pair from localStorage

Comment: Yeah, couldn't really do anything with that in a snippet. Also I haven't done much with localStorage, at least not for a while. Should be able to get more about that from these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_removeitem.asp