# How do I delete a specific localStorage when someone click a "trash" icon, which gets rid of it frontend but not local

Tags: javascript, local-storage, backend, web-frontend

I have this

```
const addForm = document.querySelector('.add')
const list = document.querySelector('.todos')
const search = document.querySelector('.search input')
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : []

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))


function noenter() {
    return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); }
```

this is how I had it originally

```
list.addEventListener('click', e => {

    if(e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
        e.target.parentElement.remove()
        localStorage.removeItem(itemsArray[0]) // I'm trying this but doesn't do anything....
        console.log(localStorage.get) // left off need to remove storage
    }

})
```

Initially, when you click the delete icon, it will remove the parent of the class, and that's how it deletes it from the web temp, but it never actually saved aka stored it. I'm trying to add that function right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array item from localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question and code correctly, you should rebuild your `itemsArray` without the item that should be deleted, and store it back on localStorage, something like:

```
const itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')); // get data from LS
itemsArray.splice(0, 1); // remove the item on position 0
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray)); // save it back to LS
```

On your code, the call to `localStorage.removeItem(itemsArray[0])` is trying to remove from the `localStorage` and item which the index is the value of `itemsArray[0]`. This item is unlikely to exist, and that's why your code is having no effect.

Comment: I guess my followup question to that is, how do I figure out what position someone is clicking. Originally all I had was if ti contains delete class remove parent... How do I translate that to a specific position. If I had a list from top to bottom.

Comment: I replaced 
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : []

with your code, but now when I refresh the tab it doesn't stay