# Remove an element from the key of the localStorage session Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have set a key on local-storage. I am using local-storage to save the key of my product id where the customers are not logged in.

So, I have the following data on my local-storage.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
//resuts
['34',76,'34']
```

Now, in the checkout page, what can I do if the user want to remove a single product? I have done the following but it does not work.

```
$('.delete_item').on('click', function() {
   let delete_data = $(this).val();
   my_product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
   delete my_product[delete_data];
   localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(my_product));
});
```

Comment: Use filter method.

Comment: `products` is an array, not an object, so the `delete` operator won't work as-intended.

Comment: `my_product` is an array, hence... -> [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) / [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array item from localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how to remove an element from an array, `delete` keyword works with deleting object properties.
With arrays, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
The code should be like this:

```
$('.delete_item').on('click', function() {
   let delete_data = $(this).val();
   my_product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

   // Change this line
   my_product = my_product.filter(prodId => prodId !== delete_data);

   localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(my_product));
});
```

As suggested by [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai), here is a cleaner/valid code:

```
$('.delete_item').on('click', function() {
   const deletedProduct = $(this).val();
   let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

   products = my_product.filter(prodId => prodId !== deletedProduct);

   localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
});
```

Comment: `my_product` should be renamed `products` (because it doesn't represent a single object) and it probably should be declared as a local in the function using `let`.

Comment: @Dai Your comments are valid but I wanted to make as little change as possible for the OP to get the main change hence the main idea.

Comment: Just curious, you didn't find anywhere in stack overflow any question which mentions how to remove an element from an array by key?

Comment: @aldokkani. What does 'prodId' do? It has no been declared anywhere. You answer worked but I am just curious to know the role of `prodId`.

Comment: @Eliesha [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a callback function, here I am defining an anonymous function with `prodId` as parameter.

Comment: @Zuckerberg Noted.

Comment: @Zuckerberg In computer science, you can't "remove" an element from an array by-index because array indexes logically represent memory addresses (look at C-style pointer arithmetic on arrays) and you can't "delete" memory - if you see what I mean. Languages and libraries that let you remove elements from arrays (and vectors in general) do it by copying all of the subsequent elements up-by-one to fill the previously occupied space, which is a very expensive operation and rarely actually needs to be performed by an application (it means the programmer is using the wrong data-structure)

Comment: @Zuckerberg As it is, your `products` collection is more of a "set" than an array (as the order doesn't matter, and you want to be able to add and remove individual items cheaply) - so consider using string keys instead of integer indexes - that way JavaScript will treat the object as a hashtable (though the rules on how strings-representing-integers as used as indexers is complicated - to be safe you'd want to prefix all of the strings with an alphabetic character to prevent automatic type-juggling).

Comment: @Dai just curious, why does the [splice docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Remove_1_element_at_index_3) says _"Remove" 1 element at index 3_ , as we _can't "remove" an element from an array by-index_ ?

Comment: @Zuckerberg It's fine to use the word "Remove element" in this context as shorthand for "Replace specified elements by moving subsequent elements to fill the space". Lots of List/Vector APIs (in .NET, Java, etc) use the term "Remove" as well. I'm just drawing attention to it because people unfamiliar with how computer memory works might assume that "Remove from an array" is an `O(1)` operation when it's really `O(n)`.

Comment: ...but in comparison, if you look at the interface or docs for C++'s STL `vector<T>` it only uses the term "remove" for popping the last element in the vector (which **is** an `O(1)` operation) and not for operations on elements elsewhere in the vector (which will be `O(n)`):  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is an array you can use all array manipulation methods such as unshift, slice, splice etc accordingly. For ex:

The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)

```
 my_product.splice(idx, 1);
 localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(my_product));
```

You will get the updated my_product array.