# Delete item from the localStorage after a click method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delete item's from a todo list that I saved in the `localStorage`.

I was thinking about doing something similar to this:

`let deleteTodos = () => {localStorage.removeItem(todos["hola"]); };`

In this part of the code :

```js
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }
});
```

And here is the whole code to give you and idea of the whole app

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector(".add");
const list = document.querySelector(".todos");
const search = document.querySelector(".search input");
var todos = [];
var todosString = localStorage.getItem("todos");
var todos = JSON.parse(todosString);

// generate new toDo's
const generateTemplate = (todos) => {
  let html = ` <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>${todos}</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
  </li>`;
  list.innerHTML += html;
};

todos.forEach((todo) => generateTemplate(todo));

// submit the todo
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
  if (todo.length) {
    todos.push(todo);
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    generateTemplate(todo);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});

// delete todo's

list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }
});

// filter the toDo's

const filterTodos = (term) => {
  Array.from(list.children)
    .filter((todo) => !todo.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(term))
    .forEach((todo) => todo.classList.add("filtered"));

  Array.from(list.children)
    .filter((todo) => todo.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(term))
    .forEach((todo) => todo.classList.remove("filtered"));
};

search.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  const term = search.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  filterTodos(term);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? What's not working? Are you trying to delete a single todo item or the entire list? We need more context to better assist you.

Comment: why you are using ["hola"]?. I think you just should do `localStorage.removeItem("todos")`

Comment: `todos` is an array of the todo elements, right? And you add by pushing an item into the array and setting the localstorage item to the stringified array. So, removing is the same; remove the item from the array and set the localstorage item to the stringified array

Comment: The best option is to remove it from the `todos` array, then update the localstorage instead of removing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array item from localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving the stringified todos in localStorage under "todos", you cannot then delete a single item via `localStorage.removeItem(todos["hola"])`.

Without commenting on whether you should be using localStorage in this way, to delete an item you'll need to replace the entire object in localStorage:

```js
const deleteTodo = (label) => {
  // get the items from storage
  const oldTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));

  // delete the specified item. (however you need to do it. this might not work with your specific data structure)
  const newTodos = oldTodos.filter(({ label: x }) => x === label);

  // re-reserialize to local storage
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
};
```

Comment: and then I have to call the function `daleteTodo` inside the  `list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }
});`   ????? Because i don't get how to conect that function with the click event, sorry if it's a silly question but i started to code 3 months ago.