# How to remove a specific item from a Local Storage array?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a [To Do List (codepen)](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/YzWeMaz) app and I am stuck on removing a specific item from Local Storage. I feel like I have the right code, but It's not working. Here's an overview:

Adding a few tasks sets those tasks in Local Storage. I'm trying to remove that task item when a user clicks the green "checkmark" on that task:

Here's my `completeDelete` function that moves the task into the "completed" category, and tries to remove that task from Local Storage:

```
const completeDelete = (e) => {
  let checks = results.querySelectorAll(".fa-check"); //Checkmark
  let deletes = results.querySelectorAll(".fa-times");

  //Complete Task:
  checks.forEach((check) => {
    
    if (e.target === check) {
      let closestTask = check.closest(".task"); //The task element
      let taskText = closestTask.firstElementChild.textContent; //the task text, to be removed
      
      closestTask.remove();
      
      removeTaskFromLS(taskText); //The function that removes the task:
      
   }
```

### Here's the Remove Task function:

```
const removeTaskFromLS = (task) => {
  let storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
  const i = storedTasks.indexOf(task);
  if (i > -1) {
    let newArr = storedTasks.splice(i, 1);
    localStorage.removeItem(JSON.stringify(task)); //not removing from Local Storage
    console.log(task);
  }
  console.log(storedTasks);
};
```

If I put the following tasks in:
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3

And check complete on Task 1, I'm left with an array of ["Task 2", "Task 3"]. But Local Storage is unaffected, and loads fully with a reload. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "local storage array" just as there's no such thing as a "JSON array". There's JSON, which is a string you pull from localStorage. There's an array, which you parse from the JSON. You then perform activities on that array. Then you stringify the array to a string (in JSON format). Then you store that string in localStorage. I would suggest a method that takes an array, stringifies it and stores it in localStorage, and another that gets the string from localStorage, parses it, and returns the array. That way, you don't think of the array as being in localstorage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array item from localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage)

Comment: That is very helpful, I appreciate the overview and game plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like the "tasks" key contains an array of tasks, and you appear to splice it off the parsed array correctly. However, you'll need to persist that spliced array back into localStorage to replace the old one.

Replace the line containing `removeItem` with:

```
localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(storedTasks));
```

Comment: Right on! That makes sense to just replace the local storage. Your code got me on the right track, it works when I replace it with the `localStorage`  variable, like so: `localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(storedTasks));`

Comment: @Sackadelic whoops, totally forgot how splice works. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) will give you string instead of Array. Use split post parsing and you will get Array.

```js
const removeTaskFromLS = (task) => {
  let storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")).split(",");
  const i = storedTasks.indexOf(task);
  if (i > -1) {
    let newArr = storedTasks.splice(i, 1);
    localStorage.removeItem(JSON.stringify(task)); //not removing from Local Storage
    console.log(task);
  }
  console.log(storedTasks);
};
```

Comment: "will give you string instead of Array" What makes you say that? The OP didn't mention having issues with malformed strings in their logs...