# session Storage remove Item javascript problem

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Solved Now - sessionStorage->array->make New Array without item -> back to sessionStorage

This is driving me nuts, and yes have looked all day for a solution.

I'm trying to remove item from the sessionStorage.  But just one item.  I can find the item, just can't remove it.  Any help would be great, Thanks

```
function removeCartItem(key) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('shopping-cart')) {
        var IsItemThere = false;
        var shoppingCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shopping-cart'));
        shoppingCart.forEach(function(item) {
            var cartItem = JSON.parse(item);
            if(cartItem.key === key){
                IsItemThere = true;
            }
        });
        if(IsItemThere == true){
            var cartArray = new Array();
            shoppingCart.forEach(function(item) {
                var cartItem = JSON.parse(item);
                if(cartItem.key != key){
                    cartItem = {
                        key: cartItem.key,
                        id: cartItem.id,
                        productName: cartItem.productName,
                        price: cartItem.price,
                        quantity: cartItem.quantity
                    };
                    var cartItemJSON = JSON.stringify(cartItem);
                    cartArray.push(cartItemJSON);
                }
            });
        }
        sessionStorage.removeItem('shopping-cart');
        var cartJSON = JSON.stringify(cartArray);
        sessionStorage.setItem('shopping-cart', cartJSON);
    }
}
```

This is how each item look like, and yes, the alert does popup
{"key":14759,"id":"1","productName":"Sample Product 1","price":"12.77","quantity":"1"}

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: make sure `'TheCart'` (*`.getItem('TheCart'));`*) is equal to `item` you're passing in `.removeItem(item)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748298/remove-array-item-from-localstorage

Comment: Do you have an `item` key in your Session Storage? It seems you only have the key `"TheCart"`. `shoppingCart` is the object that has `item`, not the Session Storage. In your Session Storage, you need to _set_ the updated JSON, not remove something.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; is the item stored in an array in session storage, or is it stored separately? You appear to be removing a *separate* item (and not modifying the cart array, or storing it back into session storage).

Comment: You are mixing up your *array items* and *sessionStorage items*, those are completely different things.

Comment: Look like what people are saying is get the sessionStorage convert to array, remove element and add back to sessionStorage?

Comment: *(Tangential, but you're parsing the cart data already; why is the item also being parsed?)*

Comment: (Tangential, but you're parsing the cart data already; why is the item also being parsed?) To find the item by key

Comment: @SiNiSi **You've already parsed the cart**. Everything in the cart has been JSON-parsed. Do you **actually** JSON-escape each item so it has to be parsed **again**? If so... why?

Comment: Sorry Dave I see what you taking about I will fix that.  But my main problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

Solved Now - sessionStorage->array->make New Array without item -> back to sessionStorage